# OBIEE 11G Catalog Manager offline mode not show

Tags: oracle11g, migration, catalog, obiee

I have tried to access my RPD file, in local (Windows 7) from my Client of OBIEE.
I want to migrate some reports between the two environments.
When I open a catalog, I cant select offline, only online:

[image]

How could I change the configuration to allow me to select online?

Comment: Are there any errors you can locate? I have a feeling I might know whats going on here, but I would need an error message to confirm. I would be looking for an error along the lines of: 32bit:\bifoundation\web\bin\sawjniapi3r.dll: Can't find dependent library files. or 64bit: no sawjniapi643r.dll in java-library.path. Also, what is the exact version you are on? Ex. 11.1.1.7.0

Comment: I dont see any error. My computer is 64 bits and Catalog Manager Version is 11.1.1.7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, what I believe is the "Official" answer to your question:**

This is expected behavior. User shouldn't run Catalog Manager in offline mode in a client-only installation.

Catalog Manager is available with OBIEE Server install on Server Side as well, and can be invoked using

`ORACLE_INSTANCE/bifoundation/OracleBIPresentationServicesComponent/coreapplication_obips1/catalogmanager/runcat.sh`

Catalog Manager in OFFLINE mode via JNI loads the C++ libraries, and those *do* need an instanceconfig.xml eg whether (or not) user's home directories are hashed (or not). The C++ libraries do not even start unless the full ORACLE_INSTANCE catastrophe is available.  Hence the "runcat.cmd" we provide, which sets the INSTANCE env.

There are a series of bugs (closed as not a bug) on this issue, the only one which is public at this time is : 
Bug:14020946 - CATALOG MANAGER DOES NOT DISPLAY OFFLINE IN OPEN CATALOG

**Now, here is a hack I found that may allow you to run offline (I have not personally tried this):**

Client tool's installer does not provide all the required libraries, so the message: "sawjniapi643r.dll: Can't find dependent libraries".

After doing a standard OBIEE_Client_Tools installation, you have to provide the missing files. 
In version 11.1.1.7.0 missing files are: 
- SAWAUDITWRAPPER643R.DLL or SAWAUDITWRAPPER3R.DLL (32-bit) 
- SAWFAVORITES643R.DLL or SAWFAVORITES3R.DLL (32-bit) 
- SAWHEADLINEVIEW643R.DLL or SAWHEADLINEVIEW3R.DLL (32-bit) 
- SAWORACOREFACADE643R.DLL or SAWORACOREFACADE3R.DLL (32-bit) 
- SAWTREEMAPVIEW643R.DLL or SAWTREEMAPVIEW3R.DLL (32-bit) 
- SAWTRELLISVIEW643R.DLL or SAWTRELLISVIEW3R.DLL (32-bit) 
In 11.1.1.6.x there are other files. Nevermind

Files/folders we are looking for, are provided in full suite of BI installer in the .jar file: "filegroup1.jar". 
In ver: 11.1.1.7.0: 
* bishiphome\disk3\​​stage\Components\oracle.bi.bifndn\11.1.1.7.0\1\datafiles\filegroup1.jar 
In ver: 11.1.1.6.0: 
* bishiphome\Disk4\stage\Components\oracle.bi.bifndn\11.1.1.6.0\1\datafiles\filegroup1.jar

JAR file, as you know is a zip archive. You have to extract it.

DLL's we are looking for are in: filegroup1.jar\bifoundation\web\bin\

In general, I think it is best to copy/overwrite the entire 'bin' directory 
 copy filegroup1.jar\bifoundation\web\bin\ -> Client_Install_Folder\oraclebi\orahome\bifoundation\web\bin

In addition it is required to have a "display" directory so: 
 copy filegroup1.jar\bifoundation\web\display -> Client_Install_Folder\oraclebi\orahome\bifoundation\web 
... and "schemas" 
 copy filegroup1.jar\bifoundation\web\schemas -> Client_Install_Folder\oraclebi\orahome\bifoundation\web 
... and "messages" 
 copy filegroup1.jar\bifoundation\web\msgdb -> Client_Install_Folder\oraclebi\orahome\bifoundation\web

Without any error messages, I can't confirm whether or not this is your problem; I am only guessing.

**References:**

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/obiee-enterprise-methodology/ZxUIWyeMEuE
https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/SearchDocDisplay?_adf.ctrl-state=cgrgn49cj_9&_afrLoop=285196945762562